# data-description use on href link

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to use data-description on href link like, but description not displaying. Is some one know how to use it then please let me know. Here is the demo link http://jsfiddle.net/KNa3A/

Comment: What exactly are you trying to? And your fiddle provides no JavaScript t see your implementation

Comment: http://demo.samuli.me/wp/smartstart/ check top link like Home, Features etc. I want to display data-description of each link. I have no Idea will you please give me a link of jsfiddle so I can know.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what you want, but if what you want is a better looking tooltip (i.e the `title` attribute), you can achieve something like [this](http://downloads.sixrevisions.com/css-tooltips/index.html) [just with CSS](http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-only-tooltips/).

Comment: You can do this in just CSS using pseudo elements and content...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the :after psuedo element for this - http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/KNa3A/4/

```
.your_class:after {
    content: attr(data-description);
    display: block;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    color: red;
}
```

Set the content of the :after element to attr(data-description) and you're off.

Comment: http://demo.samuli.me/wp/smartstart/ check top link like Home, Features etc. I want to display data-description of each link.

Answer (score 0):

You have no JavaScript code there except standard Mootools library: http://jsfiddle.net/KNa3A/

data-description could be used by some JavaScript plugin, but you need to initialize it. That plugin (possibly jQuery or Mootools plugin) will then get that description and render nice thing (popover, tooltip, whatever). This should be included in that specific plugin's tutorial / quickstart / readme file.

Ps. Others suggest to use title attribute instead. That is good way to do it, unless you want something fancy. But for something fancy you will most likely need JS plugin.

Comment: http://demo.samuli.me/wp/smartstart/ check top link like Home, Features etc. I want to display data-description of each link.